# Getting XML data into combobox

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

I have a windows form with 3 comboboxes and a XML file as following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<shrtcutkeys>
    <Keysmain>
        <keychars>
            <key1>
                Ctrl
            </key1>
            <key1>
                Alt
            </key1>
            <key1>
                Shift
            </key1>
        </keychars>
    </Keysmain>
    <Seckeys>
        <keychars>
            <key2>
                Ctrl
            </key2>
            <key2>
                Alt
            </key2>
            <key2>
                Shift
            </key2>
        </keychars>
    </Seckeys>
    <Alphas>
        <keychars>
            <key3>
                a
            </key3>
            <key3>
                b
            </key3>
            <key3>
                c
            </key3>
        </keychars>
    </Alphas>
</shrtcutkeys>
```

So i would like to display  all key1 in combobox1 and all key2 in combox2 and so on so forth..tried doing this but not really working

```
DataSet dsSet = new DataSet();
            dsSet.ReadXml("C:\\Users\\jackandjill\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\highlite\\highlite\\keys.xml");
            comboBox1.DataSource = dsSet.Tables["keys"];
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "key1";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use Linq2XML:

Load the data into an [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx):
Either load from file:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(fileName);
```

or load from a string

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse( @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<shrtcutkeys>
    <Keysmain>
        <keychars>
            <key1>
                Ctrl
            </key1>
            <key1>
                Alt
            </key1>
            <key1>
                Shift
            </key1>
        </keychars>
    </Keysmain>
    <Seckeys>
        <keychars>
            <key2>
                Ctrl
            </key2>
            <key2>
                Alt
            </key2>
            <key2>
                Shift
            </key2>
        </keychars>
    </Seckeys>
    <Alphas>
        <keychars>
            <key3>
                a
            </key3>
            <key3>
                b
            </key3>
            <key3>
                c
            </key3>
        </keychars>
    </Alphas>
</shrtcutkeys>");
```

Then you can select desired items

```
var mainItems = from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("key1")
                select key.Value;
var secKeyItems = from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("key2")
                select key.Value;
var alphaItems = from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("key3")
                select key.Value;
```

You can now bind each combo to the selected result, like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = mainItems.ToList();
```

You might want to wash your XML (to remove newlines and spaces)

```
var mainItems = from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("key1")
                select key.Value.Trim();
var secKeyItems = from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("key2")
                select key.Value.Trim();
var alphaItems = from key in xmlDocument.Descendants("key3")
                select key.Value.Trim();
```

Comment: This is such a great answer, but one thing i dont understand is that why is that when i do this  var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(@"C:\\Users\\jackandjill\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\highlite\\highlite\\keys.xml"); i get an error saying  "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: To load from a file you use `XDocument.Load` instead. Besides, don't use both `@` and double backslash (`\\`). `@` turns off all escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Usinq LINQ To XML:

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(
                @"<shrtcutkeys>
                        <Keysmain>
                            <keychars>
                                <key1>
                                    Ctrl
                                </key1>
                                <key1>
                                    Alt
                                </key1>
                                <key1>
                                    Shift
                                </key1>
                            </keychars>
                        </Keysmain>
                        <Seckeys>
                            <keychars>
                                <key2>
                                    Ctrl
                                </key2>
                                <key2>
                                    Alt
                                </key2>
                                <key2>
                                    Shift
                                </key2>
                            </keychars>
                        </Seckeys>
                        <Alphas>
                            <keychars>
                                <key3>
                                    a
                                </key3>
                                <key3>
                                    b
                                </key3>
                                <key3>
                                    c
                                </key3>
                            </keychars>
                        </Alphas>
                    </shrtcutkeys>");

var key1 = xml.Descendants("key1");

foreach (var key in key1)
    comboBox1.Items.Add(key.Value.Trim());

var key2 = xml.Descendants("key2");

foreach (var key in key2)
    comboBox2.Items.Add(key.Value.Trim());

//Do the same for other keys...
```

Comment: Tks so much for showing me another reason to learn LINQ! but one thing i dont understand is that why is that when i do this var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(@"C:\\Users\\jackandjill\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\highlite\\highlite\\keys.xml"); i get an error saying "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: @JackyBoi - There is nothing wrong with your xml, but `XDocument.Parse` is for loading xml from a string, not a file name, so try doing `XDocument.Load` instead.

Comment: haha funny enough on my way to work this struck me aswell and i tried it and works fine..tks so much!